# Determine the order of XML elements in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

so I have this xml

```
<xmlTag>
  <item>etc etc</item>
  <section>etc etc</section>
  <item>etc etc</item>
  <item>etc etc</item>
  <section>etc etc</section>
<xmlTag>
```

and I want to process this in order, ie process the first item tag then the second section tag then the third item tag...etc

however when I use `simplexml_load_string()` the resultant object becomes

```
$xmlTag = {SimpleXMLElement}[2]
    item = {array} [3]
    section = {array} [2]
```

Hence it separates out the item tags and the section tags and now I have no way to determine the orderings between the item tags and the section tags....

Anyone know of an alternative way to figure out the order of the xml elements in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever dump function you're using there is misleading you (anything not [dedicated to the purpose](https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug) will, due to the large amount of "magic" supported by SimpleXML). The nodes have not been permanently separated out, it's just showing you that they *can* be accessed that way.

If you use [the `children()` method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php), you will get them in the order they are defined in the document, regardless of tag name:

```
foreach ( $xmlTag->children() as $child_name => $child ) {
     echo $child_name, "\n";
}
```

Note that `children()` doesn't actually return an array, just an "iterable" object. So unlike a real array, the same "key" can occur multiple times when you loop over it.

Comment: You probably might like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24373527/367456 - and regarding your answer, `foreach (new SimpleXMLIterator($xmlTag->asXML()) as ...` would work, too :) (not really that useful ^^)