# How to extract values from xml file and do mathematical operations?

Tags: php, xml

I want to multiply a value with another value from an xml file, it works but not as I want to. If the `$amount` is 5, when I multiply with `$eurotodollar` I still get 5 not 6.882. Is there something I am missing here...

I have the `php` code:

```
    <?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('curr.xml')or die("Error: Cannot create object");

    $eurtodollar = $xml->OrigCurrency->Cube->Rate[0];

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];
        $cur1 = $_POST['cur1'];
        if(!isset($_POST['cur2']))
        {
            echo "<center><b>Enter Values</b><br></center>";
        }else{
            $cur2 = $_POST['cur2'];
        }
        if($cur1=="EUR" AND $cur2=="USD")
        {
            echo "<center><b>Your Converted Amount is:</b><br></center>";
            echo "<center>" . $amount*$eurtodollar . "</center>";
        }
}
    ?>
```

and the `xml` code:

```
<body>
    <OrigCurrency val="Euro">
        <Cube date="2014-06-20">
            <Rate currency="USD">1.3764</Rate>
            <Rate currency="CHF">1.2079</Rate>
            <Rate currency="GBP">0.8731</Rate>
        </Cube>
    </OrigCurrency>
</body>
```

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `echo $eurtodollar` to see what simplexml is spitting out?

Comment: yes but it was perfect with echo, just after the calculate was the problem

Comment: @MarcB: That would cast it to string, which would not explain why it's 1 all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think making the variable float will fix your issue. To get a float value from the variable with the SimpleXMLElement, you can use the [`floatval`](http://php.net/floatval) function:

```
floatval($var);
```

Fpr example you could use

```
$result = $amount * floatval($eurtodollar)
```

Comment: i see it works like that, i just want to thank you. if there is another way to do it, you just post it here

Answer (score 1):

What you experience here is that if you do:

```
 $eurtodollar = $xml->OrigCurrency->Cube->Rate[0];
```

The variable `$eurtodollar` contains an object of type **SimpleXMLElement**.

When you now multiply that object with a number in PHP, PHP has to do some type conversions because you can not multiply an object with a number (as you might know, you can only multiply one number with another number ;) ):

```
 var_dump(1 * $eurtodollar); # int(1)
```

So that gets you back the integer 1 which might be unexpected. That is because when you [multiply an integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) with an object, [the object is cast](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)  to Boolean which is `TRUE`<sup>[1]</sup> which then is converted to integer which is `1` (one).

So what you write there is

```
    1 * SimpleXMLElement <Rate currency="USD">1.3764</Rate>
=>  1 * TRUE
=>  1 * 1
==  1
```

However if you cast the object into a *float*, then PHP first tries to convert the object into a string (which is possible with a SimpleXMLElement as with any object that has the [`__toString()` method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)) and the string is then converted into a *float*  which is done by PHP as well:

```
var_dump(1 * (float) $eurtodollar); # double(1.3764)
```

This then is:

```
    1 * (float) SimpleXMLElement <Rate currency="USD">1.3764</Rate>
=>  1 * (float) "1.3764"
=>  1 * 1.3764
==  1.3764
```

Likewise you could just only cast to string and PHP then will convert it to a number again:

```
var_dump(1 * (string) $eurtodollar); # double(1.3764)
```

This is then:

```
    1 * (string) SimpleXMLElement <Rate currency="USD">1.3764</Rate>
=>  1 * "1.3764"
=>  1 * 1.3764
==  1.3764
```

And this is the whole magic.

See [String conversion to numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) for more information.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Normally all objects in PHP would cast to Boolean `TRUE`, however **SimpleXMLElement** is special here as it can be Boolean `FALSE` as well when empty (e.g. `<Rate></Rate>`). With that as first element, you would get 0 all the time.

Comment: Thanks. I personally also prefer the casts like `(float) $var` over the function call `floatval($var)` because IMHO it's more descriptive what the code does (type conversion).

Comment: that is what I did. i am newbie, i still have alot of issues with all these

Comment: tip: what is special in PHP is that you can put every type into the same variable. that's why PHP does this [*type juggling*](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) based on occasion.

Comment: first i thought it is not possible, but it is, this site saves lives.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('curr.xml')or die("Error: Cannot create object");

$eurtodollar = $xml->OrigCurrency->Cube->Rate[0];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $cur1 = $_POST['cur1'];
    if(!isset($_POST['cur2']))
    {
        echo "<center><b>Enter Values</b><br></center>";
    }else{
        $cur2 = $_POST['cur2'];
    }
    if($cur1=="EUR" AND $cur2=="USD")
    {
        echo "<center><b>Your Converted Amount is:</b><br></center>";
        echo "<center>" . ($amount* (float) $eurtodollar) . "</center>";
    }
```

}
    ?>